# tooltip text erases panel drawing in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawstring, paintcomponent

I have a `JPanel` on which some drawing is performed using `paintComponent` method and after that when ever a user clicks on the `JPanel` a string is drawn (or any drawing) on it and as the user moves mouse over the `JPanel` it shows the coordinates in the tooltip of the `JPanel`.

1) The problem is that when the tooltip comes over the drawn string it erases it but this tooltiptext has no erasing effect on the drawing part which I performed in `paintComponent` method. I am not able to understand that why this is happening.

2) And also when I draw string on click and then minimize and restore my application my drawn strings are gone.

Hope u all understand what I mean to say.

Here is the code :

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    drawBorder(graphics2D);
    drawGrid(graphics2D);
}

private void drawBorder(Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(borderStroke));
    graphics2D.drawRoundRect(panelStartLoc.x, panelStartLoc.y, panelBorder.width,
            panelBorder.height, borderRoundness, borderRoundness);
}

private void drawGrid(Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(gridCellStroke));

    for (int row = gridStartLoc.x; row < panelBorder.getWidth(); row += cellWidth + cellHorGap) {
        for (int col = gridStartLoc.y; col < panelBorder.getHeight(); col += cellHeight + cellVerGap) {
            graphics2D.drawRoundRect(row, col, cellWidth, cellHeight, cellRoundness, cellRoundness);
        }
    }
}

public void drawSubjectAtClickLoc(int subjectCode) {
    Color color = getBackground();
    String drawString = null;
    int subjectDrawXLoc = cellClickLoc.x + 4;
    int subjectDrawYLoc = (cellClickLoc.y + cellHeight) - 3;
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();

    if (subjectCode == SUBJECT_CLEAR) {
        graphics2D.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics2D.fillRoundRect(cellClickLoc.x + 2, cellClickLoc.y + 2, cellWidth - 4, 
                cellHeight - 4, cellRoundness, cellRoundness);
        return;
    }
    if (subjectCode == SUBJECT_HUMAN) {
        color = Color.WHITE;
        drawString = "H";
    }
    if (subjectCode == SUBJECT_RESOURCE) {
        color = Color.GREEN;
        drawString = "R";
    }

    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics2D.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 26));
    graphics2D.setColor(color);
    graphics2D.drawString(drawString, subjectDrawXLoc, subjectDrawYLoc);
}
```

thanx in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your screen is covered, Java calls `paintComponent()` to fix the screen. If you draw outside of the `paintComponent()` method, then when the screen is fixed up, your extra drawings will be erased.

So don't do it that way: do all of your drawing in `paintComponent()`. When the user clicks somewhere, add the string you want to draw and the coordinates to a data structure of some kind (i.e., a list of objects, each object containing a String and some coordinates), then call `repaint()`. In your `paintComponent()` method, look in that data structure and draw the strings.

Comment: so can i say that drawing applications maintain a data structure of drawn objects in the memory.. is that so?

Comment: *"drawing applications maintain a data structure of drawn objects in the memory."*  Note the 'data structure' might be a `BufferedImage` as shown in t[his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216139/418556).  In some ways it is easier, but this approach (list of things to paint) is better if you wish to offer 'undo' for the user edits.