# Using addMouseListener() and paintComponent() for JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, actionlistener

This is a follow-up to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui) question. I've simplified things as much as I could, and it still doesn't work! Although the good thing I got around using `getGraphics()`.

A detailed explanation on what goes wrong here is massively appreciated. My suspicion is that something's wrong with the the way I used `addMouseListener()` method here.

EDIT completely rewrote the code. Still does not work properly though.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class RunClass{

    static MainClass1 inst1 = new MainClass1();



    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.add(inst1);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setTitle("NewPaintToolbox");
        frame1.setSize(200, 200);
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
        frame1.setVisible(true);                
    }
}

class MainClass1 extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    int xvar=30;
    int yvar=30;
    //static PaintClass22 inst1 = new PaintClass22();


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        xvar = arg0.getX();
        yvar = arg0.getY();
        repaint(xvar,yvar,10,10);

    }   

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        xvar = arg0.getX();
        yvar = arg0.getY();
        repaint(xvar,yvar,10,10);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(xvar, yvar, 10, 10);     

    }



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the mouseListener to the panel. That doesn't happen by default as you might have expected ;-)

```
MainClass1() {
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

BTW: it's not recommended to expose public api that's only meant to be used internally. So instead of letting the panel implement MouseListener (which enforces the public exposure), let the panel create and use a MouseListener:

```
private MouseListener mouseListener;
MainClass1() {
   mouseListener = createMouseListener();
   addMouseListener(mouseListener);
}

protected MouseListener createMouseListener() {
    MouseListener l = new MouseListener() {

    }
   return l;
}
```

BTW 2: calling the repaint on the limited area isn't exactly what you want (?) - it *temporarily* adds the squares to the painting, they are lost whenever the whole panel is repainted (same effect as with getGraphics). Depending on what you really want,

- paint a single square at the most recently clicked position: call repaint()
- paint squares at all locations ever clicked: store the locations in a list and implement repaint to loop over that list. Here you may call the repaint with parameters, but why bother?

Comment: OK thanks, this worked. Yes, I need to keep the user's input if changes have been added (e.g. window resized). Also is it possible to avoid running `paintComponent` before `MouseActionListener` is implemented?

Answer (score 7):

This is not an immediate answer to your question, but knowing (or at least suspecting) what it is that you wish to offer (a simple paint program), I suggest starting with this approach based around a `BufferedImage` as the painting surface..

[image: Basic paint app.]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class BasicPaint {

    /** Reference to the original image. */
    private BufferedImage originalImage;
    /** Image used to make changes. */
    private BufferedImage canvasImage;
    /** The main GUI that might be added to a frame or applet. */
    private JPanel gui;
    /** The color to use when calling clear, text or other 
     * drawing functionality. */
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;
    /** General user messages. */
    private JLabel output = new JLabel("You DooDoodle!");

    private BufferedImage colorSample = new BufferedImage(
            16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private int activeTool;
    public static final int SELECTION_TOOL = 0;
    public static final int DRAW_TOOL = 1;
    public static final int TEXT_TOOL = 2;

    private Point selectionStart; 
    private Rectangle selection;
    private boolean dirty = false;
    private Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(
            3,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,1.7f);
    private RenderingHints renderingHints;

    public JComponent getGui() {
        if (gui==null) {
            Map<Key, Object> hintsMap = new HashMap<RenderingHints.Key,Object>();
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            renderingHints = new RenderingHints(hintsMap); 

            setImage(new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,3,5,3));

            JPanel imageView = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            imageView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480,320));
            imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageView);
            imageView.add(imageLabel);
            imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new ImageMouseMotionListener());
            imageLabel.addMouseListener(new ImageMouseListener());
            gui.add(imageScroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
            tb.setFloatable(false);
            JButton colorButton = new JButton("Color");
            colorButton.setMnemonic('o');
            colorButton.setToolTipText("Choose a Color");
            ActionListener colorListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(
                            gui, "Choose a color", color);
                    if (c!=null) {
                        setColor(c);
                    }
                }
            };
            colorButton.addActionListener(colorListener);
            colorButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(colorSample));
            tb.add(colorButton);

            setColor(color);

            final SpinnerNumberModel strokeModel = 
                    new SpinnerNumberModel(3,1,16,1);
            JSpinner strokeSize = new JSpinner(strokeModel);
            ChangeListener strokeListener = new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                    Object o = strokeModel.getValue();
                    Integer i = (Integer)o; 
                    stroke = new BasicStroke(
                            i.intValue(),
                            BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                            BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                            1.7f);
                }
            };
            strokeSize.addChangeListener(strokeListener);
            strokeSize.setMaximumSize(strokeSize.getPreferredSize());
            JLabel strokeLabel = new JLabel("Stroke");
            strokeLabel.setLabelFor(strokeSize);
            strokeLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('t');
            tb.add(strokeLabel);
            tb.add(strokeSize);

            tb.addSeparator();

            ActionListener clearListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    int result = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;
                    if (dirty) {
                        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                gui, "Erase the current painting?");
                    }
                    if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        clear(canvasImage);
                    }
                }
            };
            JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
            tb.add(clearButton);
            clearButton.addActionListener(clearListener);

            gui.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JToolBar tools = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
            tools.setFloatable(false);
            JButton crop = new JButton("Crop");
            final JRadioButton select = new JRadioButton("Select", true);
            final JRadioButton draw = new JRadioButton("Draw");
            final JRadioButton text = new JRadioButton("Text");

            tools.add(crop);            
            tools.add(select);          
            tools.add(draw);            
            tools.add(text);

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(select);
            bg.add(text);
            bg.add(draw);
            ActionListener toolGroupListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    if (ae.getSource()==select) {
                        activeTool = SELECTION_TOOL;
                    } else if (ae.getSource()==draw) {
                        activeTool = DRAW_TOOL;
                    } else if (ae.getSource()==text) {
                        activeTool = TEXT_TOOL;
                    }
                }
            };
            select.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            draw.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            text.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);

            gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

            gui.add(output,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            clear(colorSample);
            clear(canvasImage);
        }

        return gui;
    }

    /** Clears the entire image area by painting it with the current color. */
    public void clear(BufferedImage bi) {
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

        g.dispose();
        imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.originalImage = image;
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        canvasImage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, gui);
        g.dispose();

        selection = new Rectangle(0,0,w,h); 
        if (this.imageLabel!=null) {
            imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
        if (gui!=null) {
            gui.invalidate();
        }
    }

    /** Set the current painting color and refresh any elements needed. */
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        clear(colorSample);
    }

    private JMenu getFileMenu(boolean webstart){
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic('f');

        JMenuItem newImageItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        newImageItem.setMnemonic('n');
        ActionListener newImage = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        360, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                clear(bi);
                setImage(bi);
            }
        };
        newImageItem.addActionListener(newImage);
        file.add(newImageItem);

        if (webstart) {
            //TODO Add open/save functionality using JNLP API
        } else {
            //TODO Add save functionality using J2SE API
            file.addSeparator();
            ActionListener openListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (!dirty) {
                        JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                        int result = ch.showOpenDialog(gui);
                        if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                            try {
                                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(
                                        ch.getSelectedFile());
                                setImage(bi);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                showError(e);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // TODO
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                gui, "TODO - prompt save image..");
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
            openItem.setMnemonic('o');
            openItem.addActionListener(openListener);
            file.add(openItem);

            ActionListener saveListener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                    int result = ch.showSaveDialog(gui);
                    if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                        try {
                            File f = ch.getSelectedFile();
                            ImageIO.write(BasicPaint.this.canvasImage, "png", f);
                            BasicPaint.this.originalImage = BasicPaint.this.canvasImage;
                            dirty = false;
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            showError(ioe);
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
            saveItem.addActionListener(saveListener);
            saveItem.setMnemonic('s');
            file.add(saveItem);
        }

        if (canExit()) {
            ActionListener exit = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            exitItem.setMnemonic('x');
            file.addSeparator();
            exitItem.addActionListener(exit);
            file.add(exitItem);
        }

        return file;
    }

    private void showError(Throwable t) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                gui, 
                t.getMessage(), 
                t.toString(), 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    JFileChooser chooser = null;

    public JFileChooser getFileChooser() {
        if (chooser==null) {
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileFilter ff = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
            chooser.setFileFilter(ff);
        }
        return chooser;

    }

    public boolean canExit() {
        boolean canExit = false;
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm==null) {
            canExit = true;
        } else {
            try {
                sm.checkExit(0);
                canExit = true; 
            } catch(Exception stayFalse) {
            }
        }

        return canExit;
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar(boolean webstart){
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(this.getFileMenu(webstart));
        return mb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // use default
                }
                BasicPaint bp = new BasicPaint();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("DooDoodle!");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(bp.getGui());
                f.setJMenuBar(bp.getMenuBar(false));

                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public void text(Point point) {
        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "Text to add", "Text");
        if (text!=null) {
            Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
            g.setColor(this.color);
            g.setStroke(stroke);
            int n = 0;
            g.drawString(text,point.x,point.y);
            g.dispose();
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Point point) {
        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.setStroke(stroke);
        int n = 0;
        g.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point.x+n, point.y+n);
        g.dispose();
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    class ImageMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selectionStart = arg0.getPoint();
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.DRAW_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.TEXT_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                text(arg0.getPoint());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        gui, 
                        "Application error.  :(", 
                        "Error!", 
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selection = new Rectangle(
                        selectionStart.x,
                        selectionStart.y,
                        arg0.getPoint().x,
                        arg0.getPoint().y);
            }
        }
    }

    class ImageMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selection = new Rectangle(
                        selectionStart.x,
                        selectionStart.y,
                        arg0.getPoint().x-selectionStart.x,
                        arg0.getPoint().y-selectionStart.y);
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.DRAW_TOOL) {
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
        }

    }

    private void reportPositionAndColor(MouseEvent me) {
        String text = "";
        if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
            text += "Selection (X,Y:WxH): " + 
                    (int)selection.getX() +
                    "," +
                    (int)selection.getY() +
                    ":" +
                    (int)selection.getWidth() +
                    "x" +
                    (int)selection.getHeight();
        } else {
            text += "X,Y: " + (me.getPoint().x+1) + "," + (me.getPoint().y+1);
        }
        output.setText(text);
    }
}
```

This source is very patchy.

- It has many parts with `// TODO`
- A `dirty` attribute is declared but never used in any meaningful way.  ..

It is just something I hacked together today and thought should be shown before it hit the posting limit.

Oh, and don't go looking for any 'OO design' since I did not put any in.  If there is any, it is only by accident.  This code is intended to demonstrate what is possible and how to start doing it.

Comment: aside in both versions (great code both versions !!!), I'm awaiting more than 5 upvotes, strange ...my hat down

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! How long did it take you to make it? I regret I can't accept two answers.

Comment: I worked on it, on and off, throughout the day.  I'd been intending to offer a little 'paint app.' for a long time now.  It was your question that inspired me to DooDoodle.. :)  As to the 'tick', it is good where it is on the answer of kleopatra.  While my answer is excellent (IMO) it is not an answer to the question you asked.  The accepted answer is.  Of course, I am hoping to sway you away from extending panels for this painting. So, on the ***next* question**.. ;)

Comment: Thanks, this is truly an awesome answer, because it does much more than what I wanted: I were going to ask bout saving the image next. But we'll see...

Comment: +1 Very nice _paint_ style program, as contrasted with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) object _drawing_ program.

Answer (score 3):

Note the typo in your method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(varx, vary, 10, 10);     

}
```

Your method is named `paintComponent` while you are calling `super.paintComponents` (plural). If you override a method (and I would strongly suggest to add an `@Override` tag to avoid that due to a typo you are actually overriding nothing) like `paintComponent`, make sure to call the `super` method (the same method, and not another one).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `PaintClass11` is never used...

Secondly even if it was, you create two separate instances of the `PaintClass22`, one that is placed on the frame and one which you are trying to update...so no updates will ever occur on the screen.

You don't need two separate classes.  Merge `PaintClass11` and `PaintClass22` into a single class and add that to your frame

Comment: I followed your suggestions, please see the code. `paintComponent` works at the initialization once, but apparently something is wrong with `MouseListener`.