# Java JScrollPane Update Image

Tags: java, image, swing, jscrollpane, paint

I'm making a program that has an image that you scroll around on, and I can't figure out how to update the image if a button is pressed (For example: Adds a Green Ellipse to the image.) It already draws the image into the JScrollPane and you can scroll around, but when you click a button it doesn't refresh the image. (more details in code)
Here is the code:

```
public class PegMaster extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    //Note: not complete code
    public PegBox[] pegbox = new PegBox[9];

    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(520, 500);

    public BufferedImage canvas;
    public Graphics2D g2d;
    public JScrollPane scroller;
    JPanel panel;
    private Canvas window;

    JScrollPane pictureScrollPane;

    public PegMaster() {
        JButton button = new JButton("test");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);

        canvas = new BufferedImage((int)size.getWidth()-30, 75 * GUESSES, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2d = canvas.createGraphics();
        for(int i = 0;i<=pegbox.length-1;i++) {
           pegbox[i] = new PegBox(i, g2d);
        }
        window = new Canvas(new ImageIcon(toImage(canvas)), 1);
        //Class Canvas is a Scrollable JLabel to draw to (the image)
        pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(window);
        pictureScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)size.getWidth()-10, (int)size.getHeight()-20));
        pictureScrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        add(pictureScrollPane);

        //adds the scrollpane, but can't update the image in it
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
                //just adds the scrollpane
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        for(int i = 0;i<=pegbox.length-1;i++) {
            //pegbox[i] = new PegBox(i);
            pegbox[i].draw(g2d);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        //tried re-making the scrollpane, didn't work.
        //window = new Canvas(new ImageIcon(toImage(canvas)), 1);
        //pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(window);
        //pictureScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)size.getWidth()-10 (int)size.getHeight()-20));
        //pictureScrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        //tried imageupdate: pictureScrollPane.imageUpdate(canvas, 0, 0, 0 (int)size.getWidth()-10, (int)size.getHeight()-20);
        //remove(pictureScrollPane);
        //tried this: pictureScrollPane.revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216139/418556) which uses an image as the drawing surface.

Comment: I removed most of the non-releavant code, and the Canvas isn't java.awt.canvas, its My own code Canvas.java that extends JLabel and implements Scrollable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this class which displays an Image. This can be added to a `JScrollPane`

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    public Image img;

    public ImagePanel(Image img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Now add this class to the `JScrollPane`. To update it, just change the image reference and call the `repaint()` method on the component

Comment: It allready displays an image, just i need to update the image

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, don't use `Canvas` it's a heavy weight component, it will only cause you issues in the long run, use either `JComponent` or `JPanel`

Secondly, don't override `paint`, use `paintComponent` instead.  `paint` does a lot of work, including painting things like the border and child components.  It's better if you use `paintComponent` as it's at the right layer within the paint hierarchy for what you want do to.

Thirdly, NEVER call something like `Thread.sleep` while in the Event Dispatching Thread.  This will cause the event queue to pause and stop responding to events, making you program look like it's stalled.

Fourthly, NEVER call `repaint` (`invalidate`, `revalidate` or any method that might cause a repaint request to occur) within a paint method.  You will simply end up maxing out your CPU and you will be forced to kill the process.

Fifthly, you didn't provide the `actionPerformed` method, which is probably where all the action (and problems) are.  I'd imagin you need to call `window.repaint()` and possibly `window.invalidate()` (in reverse order), but since you didn't provided use with this code, that's simply speculation...

Comment: 1+ for digging through all of that. Great recommendations!

Comment: +1 but he said that `canvas` is his instance of `JLabel` and hence not a `heavyweight` component.

Comment: Thanks, but \ I said "not complete Code" i left out the actionlistener, and i made my own Canvas.java, extending JLabel and implementing Scrollable

Comment: By removing most of the irrelevant code, you've failed to produce a [SSCC](http://sscce.org/) which only makes it difficult to help you with specifics

Comment: @sriharshachilakapati his comment about the canvas was posted AFTER my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't solved my purpose so I researched and found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).
Please follow the link for whole example. I have added the code to refer in case the link changes.

```
public class ScrollablePicture extends JLabel
                           implements Scrollable,
                                      MouseMotionListener {

private int maxUnitIncrement = 1;
private boolean missingPicture = false;

public ScrollablePicture(ImageIcon i, int m) {
    super(i);
    if (i == null) {
        missingPicture = true;
        setText("No picture found.");
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    maxUnitIncrement = m;

    //Let the user scroll by dragging to outside the window.
    setAutoscrolls(true); //enable synthetic drag events
    addMouseMotionListener(this); //handle mouse drags
}

//Methods required by the MouseMotionListener interface:
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    //The user is dragging us, so scroll!
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
    scrollRectToVisible(r);
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (missingPicture) {
        return new Dimension(320, 480);
    } else {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }
}

public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
    return getPreferredSize();
}

public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                      int orientation,
                                      int direction) {
    //Get the current position.
    int currentPosition = 0;
    if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
        currentPosition = visibleRect.x;
    } else {
        currentPosition = visibleRect.y;
    }

    //Return the number of pixels between currentPosition
    //and the nearest tick mark in the indicated direction.
    if (direction < 0) {
        int newPosition = currentPosition -
                         (currentPosition / maxUnitIncrement)
                          * maxUnitIncrement;
        return (newPosition == 0) ? maxUnitIncrement : newPosition;
    } else {
        return ((currentPosition / maxUnitIncrement) + 1)
               * maxUnitIncrement
               - currentPosition;
    }
}

public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                       int orientation,
                                       int direction) {
    if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
        return visibleRect.width - maxUnitIncrement;
    } else {
        return visibleRect.height - maxUnitIncrement;
    }
}

public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    return false;
}

public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
    return false;
}

public void setMaxUnitIncrement(int pixels) {
    maxUnitIncrement = pixels;
}
```