# java drawImage not working from event

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, java-2d

I have a class that extends jlabel and draw on it using paintComponent as follows
this is paintPhotos.java

```
package myApp;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
*
* @author PAGOLINA
*/
public class paintPhotos extends javax.swing.JLabel {

    public Image img; int w; int h;
public paintPhotos(Image img, int w, int h) {
    this.img = img; this.w = w; this.h = h;
    System.out.println("am paintclass");
 }
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics p) {
    System.out.println("am here");
    super.paintComponent(p);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) p;
    p.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, this);
}

}
```

when i try to draw from a constructor of another class like this (AddScore.java).

```
public AddScore() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    removeNotify();
    setUndecorated(true);
    Image imag = new  ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("img/top_bg.jpg")).getImage();
    showPix1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    showPix1.add(new paintPhotos(imag,40,40), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

the above work fine and draw the image as specified.

but when i try to draw the image from an actionperform event of another class (AddScore.java) like this.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Image imag = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("img/top_bg.jpg")).getImage();
            showPix1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            showPix1.add(new paintPhotos(imag,20,20), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

the above statement did not work as the paintcomponent is not working,
what am i doing wrong?

Can someone pls help me on this cos i have try all posible method to call my paintPhotos class yet is not working, what is wrong with this code?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
Image imag = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("img/top_bg.jpg")).getImage();
        showPix1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        showPix1.add(new paintPhotos(imag,20,20), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: 1) *" i have a class that extends jlabel and draw on it using paintComponent"*  Why?  Draw on a `BufferedImage` and display it in a label, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208574/using-addmouselistener-and-paintcomponent-for-jpanel/12216139#12216139). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: You already added the components to your GUI. What you need at the `actionPerformed()` method is simply to update the image of `PaintPhotos` class and call `repaint()`

Answer (score 5):

1. put `Image` as [Icon / ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)
2. in this case don't load images on fly, load that as local variable
3. for `Icon`/`ImageIcon` in `JLabel` to use proper [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
4. common issue is `Icon`/`ImageIcon` doesn't returns any exceptions, have to test for `null value`
5. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: doing that you may not be able to draw the image to a specific size,